# Unable to integrate ngx_uploader to angular 6. "Cannot find module 'ngx-uploader'"

Tags: angular, ngx-uploader

I am trying to use the ngx-uploader module for angular 6 but I keep getting the same error. I'm new with angular so I don't really understand what happens.

I install with.

```
npm install file:ngx-uploader
```

and also

```
npm install "https://github.com/bleenco/ngx-uploader.git"
```

this created a folder in node_modules/ngx-uploader-demo

I tried to import

```
import { NgxUploaderModule } from 'ngx-uploader';
import { NgUploaderModule } from 'ngx-uploader/src/ngx-uploader/module/ngx-uploader.module';
```

What I can be doing wrong?

thanks a lot for any clue

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Comment: @pelirroja Have you followed this documentation (https://github.com/bleenco/ngx-uploader) or not???

Comment: Thansk very much, i solve the problem, i change in my app.module